# How can i filter 'simple' navigation properties from reverse navigation properties of EntityType in EntityFramework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

```
ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext; 
MetadataWorkspace workspace = objContext.MetadataWorkspace; 
EntityType table = workspace.GetEdmSpaceType((StructuralType)workspace.GetItem<EntityType>(type.FullName, DataSpace.OSpace)) as EntityType;
ReadonlyMetadataCollection<NavigationProperty> properties = table.NavigationProperties;
```

There are two types of navigation properties in `properties` collection: `Foo` and `ICollection<Boo>`, and i need to get only `Foo`, not `ICollection<Boo>`.